# .Net Core Web Api to Docker Container Mac

Tags: macos, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, parallels

I have a mac and parallels with windows 10. I compiled the webapi template in visual studio 2017 on windows without docker support to a folder on my mac. For some reason, I can't get the docker image to run (hello-world image works fine). Docker is installed on the Mac. Here are my steps:

```
dotnet restore ./WebApplication1.sln
dotnet publish ./WebApplication1.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish
```

Here is my docker file located in the project directory

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:latest
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", “WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Calling docker commands from the terminal

```
docker build WebApplication1 -t WebApplication1

docker run -d -p 5000:5000 WebApplication1
```

This gives me a container id but it never starts. I hope I am missing something simple. Please advise.

Comment: do you have something in docker logs?

Comment: please run `docker logs <CONTAINER_ID>` to check for errors, another way to be sute if in /app are all the requires dll's you can add `RUN ls /app` just after the `COPY` entry

Comment: I will try that. thanks

Comment: I'm thinking it was the quote since I copied that docker example from the web.

Answer (score 0):

Using docker-compose solved the issue. There could have been some type of syntax error or typo in my previous post. It is worth it to use parallels, visual studio, and a mac. Running docker on anything less than Windows 10 enterprise is not supported with the latest version of docker.

```
version: '2'

services:
  webapplication3:
    image: webapplication3
    build:
      context: ./WebApplication3
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Docker File

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:latest
    ARG source
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 80
    COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
    RUN ls /app
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication3.dll"]
```